# Only blue geometries shown for protobuf vector tiles in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I'm trying to use my vector tile server with [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/), that is a widely-used, open-source JavaScript library for interactive maps. It is often used for embedding maps in websites and offers various features for customizing the map's appearance and interactivity.

I have this `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.vectorgrid/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="width: 1200px; height: 800px;"></div>

<script src="./index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this `index.js`:

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

// --- LEAFLET
let token;

// Initialize your Keycloak
const keycloak = new Keycloak({
    url: 'myKeycloakURL',
    realm: 'myRealm',
    clientId: 'myCLientId'
});

keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required', checkLoginIframe: false}).then((authenticated) => {
    console.log(authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated');
    console.log(keycloak.token);
    token = keycloak.token;

    if (token) {
        initializeMap();
    }
});

function initializeMap() {
    if (token) {
        // Initialize your Leaflet Map
        const map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 5);

        // Add a base layer
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);


        // Add Vector Grid Layer 1
        const vectorTileOptions1 = {
            fetchOptions: {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            },
            rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
            vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                'sliced': function (properties, zoom) {
                    return {
                        fillColor: 'red',
                        fillOpacity: 0.5,
                        stroke: true,
                        fill: true,
                        color: 'red',
                        weight: 10,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                    }
                }
            },
            interactive: true,
            getFeatureId: (f) => f.id,
        };

        const vectorGrid1 = L.vectorGrid.protobuf('http://localhost:8080/tiles/test1/{z}/{x}/{y}', vectorTileOptions1).addTo(map);

        // Attach popup event
        vectorGrid1.on('click', function (e) {
            const properties = e.layer.properties;
            const content = `<h3>${properties.name || 'Unknown'}</h3>`;  // Assume that your data might contain a "name" field

            // You can place the popup at the event latlng or on the layer.
            L.popup()
                .setContent(content)
                .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                .openOn(map);
        });
    }
}
```

for render a map with 2 layers: `L.tileLayer` and `L.vectorGrid`.

But [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) doesn't fill the geometries and by the way shows only BLUE geometries and not RED or GREEN.  What I missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the layer name, in this case default, to match the one defined inside vectorTileLayerStyles:

```
                vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                    // A plain set of L.Path options.
                    default: {
                        weight: 0,
                        fillColor: '#ff0',
                        fillOpacity: 1,
                        fill: true
                    },
                },
```